# Swift: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift

I have a simple code in Swift and when I run this code Xcode returns me an error that is displayed in the code below. Are there any solutions to solve it?

**My code:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var mangedObjectContext
@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: ToDoItem.getAllToDoItems()) var toDoItems:FetchedResults<ToDoItem>
```

**Error on last line higher:**

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

**Continue of code:**

```
@State private var newToDoItem = ""

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        List{
            Section(header: Text("Whats next?")){
                HStack{
                    TextField("New item", text: self.$newToDoItem)
                    Button(action: {

                    }){
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                            .imageScale(.large)
                    }
                }
            }.font(.headline)
        }
    }

    .navigationBarTitle(("My list"))
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

CODE in contentview.swift

```
let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
```

Comment: How is the fetch request defined? Have you checked that your AppDelegat class is set up correctly?

Comment: Can you please also share the part of your code where you inject the `managedObjectContext` in the environment?

Comment: I have this. Something is not correct and I don't know what.`let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)`